# How to slide my div over another div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, dom, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a menu using jquery. When my sub-menu slides, the lower part of the page slides down. I want that lower part to reamin fixed and sub-menu slide over it.

- **Below is the body of the page:**

  DashBoard
                  
                      
                      AB

  Hello world, this is menu page

Dashboard is the main menu item. **A** and **B** are sub-menu items, which slides dowm from main menu item. **Hello World** is rest of the page, which gets slided down :( .

**jquery function to slide sub-menu **

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#divsubMenu1').hide();
            $('#tdMenu1').hover(
                        function () { $('#divsubMenu1').slideDown("slow"); }
                        , function () { $('#divsubMenu1').slideUp("fast"); }
                        );
            });
 </script>
```

What changes can make my below div fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `css` to overcome this issue

```
position:absolute; 
z-index:5;
```

use this style attribute on you drop-down sub menu.

Here are few useful links
http://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/